# How to change subnet to login in OpenVPN client.conf?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, route

I have an access to different subnets. How can I modify client.conf to login (or at least able to route) in another subnet? E.g. now I get IP address in 10.132.193.0/24 subnet, but I want to get IP in 10.132.252.0/22.

My current client.conf looks like:

```
client
dev tap
remote vpn1.r61.net
remote vpn2.r61.net
nobind
persist-key
auth-user-pass auth.txt
comp-lzo
verb 3

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably vpn1 is providing 10.132.193.0/24 and vpn2 is providing 10.132.252.0/22.

If there are multiple remote lines in a client config, the client will attempt to connect to the first one. If that fails, it will move on the the next and so on until it gets a connection or it runs out of remote systems to try. At ant time a client config will only have one connection.

If vpn2 does provide the subnet you want, then you can list vpn2 before vpn1

```
remote vpn2.r61.net
remote vpn1.r61.net
```

If you want to connect to both subnets, you have to have a separate client config file for each connection. Depending on what the server pushes you may have to manually reconfigure the routing.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I tried it, but unfortunately vpn1.r61.net and vpn2.r61.net refer to same "bad" subnet.

Comment: In that case you need to connect to the VPN server that is providing the subnet you want surely ?